# Facing difficulty in bootstrap modal

Tags: php

I am working on placement management website, facing difficulty while checking if student is eligible for apply for a particular company, I have 2 tables in backend 1.company 2.Student.I have used modal for viewing each company details and checking the eligibility. Here's the code.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<form method="post">
        
        <button type="submit" name="check" class="btn btn-primary" >Check eligibility
        </button>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['check'])){
          echo "success";
           $loginuser=$_SESSION['stdid'];

                $query="select school_per from student s, company c where s.school_per>=c.cut_10 and sid='$loginuser'";
                $runquery1 = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                  
                if($runquery1)
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("successful") </script>';
                    header("location:login.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Unsuccessful1") </script>';
                }
        }

        ?>
</form>

      </div>
```

`$loginuser=$_SESSION['stdid'];` I used this because to check eligibility of the particular student who has logged in so "stdid" is primary key in student table and student have logged in using "stdid".

PROBLEM: `{if(isset($_POST['check']))` The if loop is not getting executed its directly taking me to else but everything looks perfect in syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<button type="submit" name="check" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

To:

```
<input type="submit" name="check" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

Comment: Replace button with input field and then try again. Thanks.

Comment: @Ferran Buireu
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<form method="post">
    
    <input type="submit" name="check" class="btn btn-primary" value="Check eligibility">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['check'])){
        if($_POST['check']=='Check eligibility'){
            echo "success";
            $loginuser=$_SESSION['stdid'];

            $query="select school_per from student s, company c where s.school_per>=c.cut_10 and sid='$loginuser'";
            $runquery1 = mysqli_query($con,$query);
              
            if($runquery1)
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("successful") </script>';
                header("location:login.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Unsuccessful1") </script>';
            }
            
        }
    }?>
```